# Select Values from Dictionary as List of Strings

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary with following Structure

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

I want to extract all the values of the above dictionary and pass as list of strings to another method.

like
`MyMethod(List<string>)`
Do we have an efficient way to do this without foreach loop?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean you want *all values* as a flat list, you can use LINQ:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var allValues = myDict.Values.SelectMany(v => v).ToList();
```

[`.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) will flatten the enumerable returned from the expression `v => v`.

If you're using .NET Core in Visual Studio, you might need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the file.